# How to generate a string with fixed format in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a Database for University Management with the Tables :

`Department(Id, Name, Code)
 Student(Id, Name, Email, EnrollDate, RegNo, Department)`

I want to enroll a student. when he or she enrolled RegNo will generate automatically. Like this format --XXX.

```
Example : CSE-2017-001, EEE-2016-002, BBA-2014-015.
```

Last 3 part increment auto when a student enroll in a particular department.
How can I do this in Sql Server Management Studio.

Comment: add some sample data & desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution.

1 - creates `SEQUENCE` for keep id. Or you can use table identity.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SeqStudentIDs AS INT
MINVALUE 1
CYCLE;
```

2 - Create `TRIGGER` for update `RegNo` after insert.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_Student_ForCreateRegNo ON Student AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Student set 
        RegNo = CONCAT( (SELECT TOP 1 Code FROM Department WHERE Id = inserted.Department ) , '-' , DATEPART(YEAR,inserted.EnrollDate), '-', RIGHT('000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,(NEXT VALUE FOR SeqStudentIDs )),3) )
    FROM Student INNER JOIN inserted ON Student.Id = inserted.Id
END
```

Comment: One thing, If I want the RegNo as department wise, what can I do? Like a student enroll in CSE department, the last 3 digit of his RegNo is 001, then next student also in CSE department 002. That time no student enrolled in EEE department yet, when a student enrolled in EEE department the last 3 digit of his RegNo will be 001, not 003. Do you understand the problem?

Comment: You need to create and use different `SEQUENCE` objects for different departments. Like `SeqStudentIDsForCSE`, `SeqStudentIDsForEEE`, etc.
And use case for select appropriate sequence. Like as, `CASE WHEN Department ='EEE' THEN (NEXT VALUE FOR SeqStudentIDsForEEE) WHEN ...END,